# Minecraft Realms, Repeat Invalid ID 1.9

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

So I've been trying to log into a friend of mine in Korea's Realm, but it keeps saying I have an invalid ID. This happens many many times in a row. I'm starting to think my client is at fault, since I have a verified Mojang account.  Any ideas on what I should do?

Answer (score 2):

This is what you should do: if your running Minecraft forge, it won't work. Running Minecraft 1.8.X? It won't work. If it still is not working then do the following: Exit Minecraft, Close the launcher, Re-Open the launcher, **make sure your using the latest Minecraft version and not forge or other mod-loaders** hit play, realms, and join the realm.
If your game is still not working try searching google `Why is Minecraft realms not working on (Version)`